# Different identity files when jumping through hosts and using a single ssh config file

Tags: ssh, proxy

Let's say I have the following setup:

```
    ssh       ssh
A ------> B ------> C
    ^          ^
 using A's   using B's
   key         key
```

I'm trying to configure this in `.ssh/config` in the host `A` as follows:

```
Host C
    HostName C.com
    IdentityFile path_to_key_1
    ProxyCommand ssh -i path_to_key_2 B -W %h:%p
```

Which identify file and path go into `path_to_key_1` and `path_to_key_2` ?

For example, does `path_to_key_1` refer to a path in `A` and `path_to_key_2` to a path in `B`? Or are they both supposed to be paths in `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ProxyCommand` is executed from 'A', this makes a connection to B that only creates a **tunnel** to 'C' which is then used for 'A' to connect to 'C'. At no point is a shell opened on B, or any ssh keys loaded from B.

If you require a key for authentication that only lives on 'B' to authenticate to 'C' you won't be able to use the 'ProxyCommand'.

Answer (score 4):

Your `.ssh/config` on host `A` should look like follows:

```
Host B
    HostName B.com
    IdentityFile path_to_key_2
Host C
    HostName C.com
    IdentityFile path_to_key_1
    ProxyCommand ssh B -W %h:%p
```

Both `path_to_key` files must exist on `A`.

I use a similar configuration in production to access nagios nrpe servers.

Edit: Changed host `C` config, removed `-i` part from `ProxyCommand ssh -i path_to_key_2 B -W %h:%p` as it was superfluous